# How can I use PowerShell to move a user in AD?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm in need of a little help. I've got little to no PowerShell experience but I'm working with a Pocket Guide by my side and my GoogleFu.

Currently, my plan is to prompt for a username and store it, use Get-ADUser with the stored username to get and store the DistinguishedName, use Move-ADObject to move the user from the DistinguishedName to the target path.

The problem I'm encountering is storing and calling these things. I have this, which gives me the info on a user. How can I isolate just the distinguished name and store it?

```
$name = read-host "Enter user name"
Get-ADUser $name
```

After storing the DN, can Move-ADObject use the stored value? I've attempted to store individual values like:

```
Move-ADobject 'CN=$name,OU=department,OU=company,DC=Domain,DC=net' -TargetPath 'OU=NonActive,OU=company,DC=Domain,DC=net'
```

But this returns "Directory object not found" as it doesn't use the stored value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

`Get-ADUser $name| Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'OU=nonactive,OU=compny,DC=domain,Dc=net'`

Comment: You need to read about powershell piping: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176927.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Just an aside on this -

Powershell can't recognise variables such as `$name` when they're enclosed in single quotation marks as the shell treats such values as literal strings.  Use double quotes to work with variables:

Eg.  `write-host '$name'` would give the output `$name`, but `write-host "$name"` would return the value in the variable.

So `Move-ADobject "CN=$name,OU=department,OU=company,DC=Domain,DC=net" -TargetPath 'OU=NonActive,OU=company,DC=Domain,DC=net'` should work as expected.  On the other hand, you will learn more interesting stuff by using the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Only for your personal interest:

CB., doing the pipeline is passing an object.
You, instead of using a string, should use an object with the command:

```
Move-ADObject
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19046992)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it could be useful for the user to understand why the command didn't work. Thanks for the clarification anyway

Answer (score 0):

Move-ADobject "CN=$name,OU=department,OU=company,DC=Domain,DC=net" -TargetPath 'OU=NonActive,OU=company,DC=Domain,DC=net' -id 'username'

will do it